# Scala JSON library that has automatic serialization (through introspection)

Tags: json, scala, jackson, jerkson

I'm looking for a good JSON library for Scala that can serialize an arbitrary object graph to JSON, without requiring me to write mapping code.

Java's Jackson does this, but it isn't native to Scala and I'm having some trouble getting it to deserialize nested generics (which I attribute to the Java type system). There's Jerkson, a Scala wrapper for Jackson, but it's been abandoned for a few years.

What do you recommend?

Comment: I think ScalaJack would help you here, https://github.com/gzoller/ScalaJack, alternatively there are a few others maintained in the list from awesome Scala repo - https://github.com/lauris/awesome-scala#json

Comment: Thanks. I just tried ScalaJack, but it doesn't seem to have automatic serialization of arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 0):

**play-json**, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11, is a good choice. It is actually a wrapper around Jackson, but provides a lot of utilities that mitigate the serilization and deserilization. For more details, https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJson

In addition, it already provides reads and writes for basic data type in Scala. All you need to do is to define a format for the model in the companion object.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
implicit val format = Json.format[YourObject]
```

This is a detailed example, https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/blob/master/app/models/User.scala

Comment: Although a fine library, play-json does *not* provide the "automatic serialization through introspection" that the OP asked for

Comment: Thanks. I've tried play-json, but as Alvara pointed out it doesn't have the automatic serialization feature I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Core Jackson does not have explicit Scala support, but Jackson Scala module:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

does support Scala datatypes.